# Which files do I need to distribute?

Tags: vb.net

I am nearing deployment time and am at a loss at to which files to package and deploy when the day comes.

Can I just pull out the executable and be done with it? Or do I need the XML docs and vshost files/manifest files?

Also, the DLLs I am using are also accompanied by an XML document inside my /Release/ folder. Do I need those or can I just grab the DLL files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At minimum, you need EXE + DLLs. If applicable, add a default config file as part of deployment.

You may want to include PDBs to help debugging.

You don't need XMLs.

Answer (score 1):

For the development machine, if you're using all default controls from Visual Studio, you only need the .exe. Just install the targeted framework. If your app is running in .NET framework 4, then you only need to install framework 4 and your .exe alone will run fine. If you're using 3rd party controls, then you need the .DLL in the same folder you have your .exe, usually.